# Modifying a numpy array in-place or how to get a reference to a numpy array to be updated

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Data class with one field, price.
I referenced the price field in another class Store.
How should it be done so that Store see modification made to price?
Here is the situation in code.

```
import numpy as np

class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.price=np.array([1,2,3])

    def increasePrice(self,increase):
        self.price=self.price*increase

class Store:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data=Data()
        self.price=self.data.price

    def updateData(self):
        self.data.increasePrice(2)
        print self.data.price #print [2,3,6]
        print self.price      #print [1,2,3]
```

The only way I find to do it is to re-referenced price.

```
class Store:
    ....
    def updateData(self):
        self.data.increasePrice(2)
        self.price=self.data.price #re-referencing price
        print self.data.price #print [2,3,6]
        print self.price      #print [2,3,6]
```

But I would like a more 'automatic' way to keep the fields sync.
I'm new to python and I'm not clear on the scoping rules.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution of this problem is not to replicate `price` in `Store` instances -- simply use `self.data.price` everywhere.

If this is not an option for some reason, you can define a property:

```
class Store(object):
    ...
    @property
    def price(self):
        return self.data.price
```

This way, the `data` property of `Store` instances will always return the current value of `self.data.price`.